# Lua - Corona SDK How to fix this or change the code to make it work properly?

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

The error shows "more than 60 upvalues"

```
ball:addEventListener( "tap", function1 )
eggs:addEventListener( "tap", function2 )
dog:addEventListener( "tap", function3 )
car:addEventListener( "tap", function4 )
...
plane:addEventListener( "tap", function52 )
```

I have programmed everyting. When I delete any 20 lines of event Listeners app works. So there are probably a limit for Event Listeners. I don't have idea how to change this as minimal as it is possible to work.

I need to use rectangles as buttons for listeners. Not variables like others ariticles.

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think there is any kind limit for number of event listerners. How does listener `function1` differentiate from `function2` ?

Comment: @ldurniat Lua limits the number of upvalues to 60 by default. This is not related to Corona

Comment: Possible duplicate of [function at line xxx has more than 60 upvalues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045077/function-at-line-xxx-has-more-than-60-upvalues)

Comment: just google the error message befor asking a question on stack overflow.

Comment: @Piglet but there is nothing about what i was writing about. I need to use Listiners to buttons which are rectangles ( not variables like in that article)

Comment: it is all about your problem. maybe you just don't get it... and how is a rectangle not a variable? try putting the functions into a table. this problem is not related to rectangles btw but to the functions you add. functions are variables as well. just read the question I linked as duplicate. see answer 2

Comment: @Piglet ohh, sorry, now i get it, thank you very much, tables works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
function function1()
  print "tapped ball"
end
function function2()
  print "tapped eggs"
end
...
ball:addEventListener( "tap", function1 )
eggs:addEventListener( "tap", function2 )
```

Try doing this:

```
ball:addEventListener( "tap", function()
  print("tapped ball")
end)
eggs:addEventListener( "tap", function()
  print("tapped eggs")
end)
```